# 100% height of a button element in html doesn't work

Tags: html, css

i am having a button element in html as below,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>  

</head>
<body style="height:100%;"> 
  <button id="chartContainer" style="height:100%;" >
  </button>          
</body>

</html>
```

i need the button to fill up the window in terms of height. On resizing the window, button should adapt itself to the window size. so i have specified height of the button to 100%, but it is not working.

See the below link in which the chart element fill the entire window, on resizing the window, the chart shrink itself with the avaible size

[Click here](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/Code/MyFirstChart/site-visitor-resize-dynamic.html)

Is it possible to fill up the button to window size?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do that, but anyways, the answer is, you need to set the `height: 100%;` for the parent element as well.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

button {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RHN9p/)</kbd>

---

As you commented that why you need `100%` height for `html` element as well, the reason is, when you don't set any height to elements, the default height is `auto` and hence when you use `100%` on child elements, it fails, because `100%` of what? So inorder to make that work, you need to set the `height` to parent elements as well, hence now you can say, that `button` height is 100% of `body` and `body` is 100% of `html` and `html` is 100% of the viewport.

Comment: Thanks Alien, its work fine... but i have another doubt, setting height to 100% to body tag alone is not enough? why we need to set the height to html tag?

Comment: @user3326265 explained in my answer :)

Comment: @NoobEditor he did tried 100% height, people don't get the logic behind this, so we cannot say he didn't tried :)

Comment: Mr. Alien , Can you tell me what are good sources to learn CSS, it always confuses me?

Comment: @SurajJain Hey there, I'm not sure about any particular resource as myself, I've read a lot of articles, books, tutorials etc.. Just to get started with, you can check this out - https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/books/jump-start-css

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks Will Check , i have some doubts in some css things, can you answer them, as i do not want to post question on here, people just downvote them/

Comment: @Mr.Alien I am failing to understand how https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen$samples/Example?revision=1281109 this is working.